# Change page title in all pages created in SiteCore

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8

Is there any way to change all page title of all pages created, at once, in Sitecore for end user? May be through database or any setting provided by Sitecore?

**EDIT:**

- I have more than 500 pages created in Sitecore admin.
- Each page has a field (which I called page title) which appears as a html page title that is `<title><.title>`.
- Now I have a requirement to change the title in all pages to something else.
- I need to have faster way to change all at once, rather opening each page, changing title, save it and publish it.

Comment: I would suggest refining your question. What is it that you wish to do to the page titles? Do you want to update them to add a particular word at the beginning/end? I can't imagine you want all pages to have the same page title. The answer, though, will probably be some a script with Sitecore Powershell Extensions (SPE).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it relates to end-user functionality and as such isn't programming/programming tools specific - OP asks for a solution without a programming element.

Answer (score 0):

The fastest way would be to use the Sitecore Powershell module to set the value for all items. Something like:

```
cd 'master:/sitecore/content'
Get-ChildItem -Recurse . | Where-Object { $_.TemplateName -match "{template name}" -and $_.Fields["Title"] -ne $null } | ForEach-Object {   
    $_.Editing.BeginEdit()
    $_.Fields["Title"].Value = "{new value}";
    $_.Editing.EndEdit()
    ""
}
```

If you don't want to use Sitecore Powershell, you can use C# to write a recursive function that loops through the tree.

Example:

```
    private void UpdateAllFieldsRecursively(Item parentItem, string templateName, string fieldName, string newValue)
{
    if (parentItem != null)
    {
        using (new SecurityDisabler())
        {
            foreach (Item childItem in parentItem.Children)
            {
                if (childItem.Fields[fieldName] != null && childItem.TemplateName == templateName)
                {
                    using (new EditContext(childItem))
                    {
                        childItem[fieldName] = newValue;
                    }
                }
                if (childItem.HasChildren)
                {
                    UpdateAllFieldsRecursively(childItem, templateName, fieldName, newValue);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Where you can call the function like so:

```
const string parentNode = "/sitecore/content";
var database = Sitecore.Context.Database;
var parentItem = database.GetItem(parentNode);

UpdateAllFieldsRecursively(parentItem, "{template name}", "Title", "{new value}");
```